# Stochastic programming: Is the linear program over the vertices the same as over the simplex?

Tags: probability, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Suppose we have a random variable $W$ with probability distribution,

$\Pr(W = w) = p_w \in [0,1], \quad w \in I  = \{1, \ldots n\}$

Consider the maximization problem:

$$\max\limits_{w \in I} \mathbb{E}[f(w)] $$

Then we have,

$\max\limits_{w \in I} \sum\limits_{w \in I} f(w)\Pr(W = w) =  \max\limits_{w \in I} \sum\limits_{w \in I} f(w)p_w  = \max\limits_{w \in I} f^Tp $

where $f = (f_w)_{w \in I}$, and $p = (p_w)_{w \in I}$

> **Question: Is this problem equivalent to:**
>
> $$\max\limits_{p \in \Delta} f^Tp $$

where $p = (p_w)_{w \in I}$ and $\Delta = \left\{p \in \mathbb{R}^n| \sum\limits_{w \in I} p_w = 1, p_w \geq 0\right\}$

Comment: Could you explain what $\max\limits_{w \in I}$ means? I do not understand what is subject to optimization here.

Comment: The tag [tag:stochastic-programming] has [recently been created](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/30111/290189).  Please consider using it.  Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what you mean by equivalent.
$$ \max_{w \in I} \mathbb{E}[f(w)] \qquad (1)$$
$$ \max_{p \in \Delta} f^T p \qquad (2)$$

If (1) has a unique solution $w^* = \arg \max_{i \in N} f_i$, then the two problems are equivalent. 
$w^*$ is optimal for (1) if and only if $p_{w^*} = 1$ is optimal for (2).
The two problems will always have the same optimal objective value.
Hope this helps.